# Как изменить значение bool на противоположное в Python в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bool

```
def hide(self):
    if self.hidden is True:
        self.hidden = False
    else:
        self.hidden = True
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте `self.hidden = not self.hidden`

```
>>> hidden = True
>>> hidden
True
>>> hidden = not hidden
>>> hidden
False
>>> hidden = not hidden
>>> hidden
True
>>>
```

Comment: То что надо. Благодарю.

Comment: @Oleg Aleynikov  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour